# AJAX post function do GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to do a post function after gettings some json files.

But when I press the button that trigger the function the result is a get not a post.

```
function post(info) {
    $.ajax({
        //type: "POST",
        method: "post",
        data: info,
        url: 'http://www.exefire.com/log',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: true,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            var texto = 'Error conectando con el servidor!';
            alert(texto);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You cannot make a **JSONP** POST request. JSONP is nothing but inserting a `<script>` element into the document, and `<script>`s are always loaded via GET.

Comment: Why you're using JSONP?

Comment: Because I'm sending info from a JSON file that I GET. I want to POST an status

Answer (score 1):

Change the dataType property from 'jsonp' to 'json'.  It is not possible to make a POST request with jsonp

```
function post(info) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: info,
    url: 'http://www.exefire.com/log',
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(request, error) {
        var texto = 'Error conectando con el servidor!';
        alert(texto);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: To be honest I don't know because

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the Url does not support CORS

Comment: If the url doesn't support CORS then this solution will not work.